# "'CREATE PROCEDURE' must be only statement in the batch" en procedimiento

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error cuando hago este procedimiento? En el que me da el siguiente error:

> 'CREATE PROCEDURE' must be only statement in the batch.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 2):

Esta pregunta suele estar solucionada. Dejo acá los links para nos duplicar pero te dejo la solución breve abajo:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147384/sql80001-incorrect-syntax-create-procedure-must-be-the-only-statement-in-the
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022645/create-procedure-must-be-the-only-statement-in-the-batch-erro
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773473/incorrect-syntax-create-procedure-must-be-the-only-statement-in-the-batch
- Y más...

Pero la solución es la siguiente:

SQL te pide que la sentencia CREATE PROCEDURE sea la única en tu archivo (pestaña/conexión/etc). Por lo tanto, lo que podés hacer es dejar esa única sentencia en ese archivo ó agregar la palabra reservada `GO` antes de las setencias que tenés arriba.

Algo así:

```
....
SELECT * FROM tabla;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE ...
```

Repito, esta solución se ve también en este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022645/create-procedure-must-be-the-only-statement-in-the-batch-erro

Espero que te sirva!